# User Profile Service Application. Unable to create a New User Profile Service Application

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

I am trying to configure Mysite to SharePoint 2013. I first tried to start User Profile Synchronization Service on my server. In that it shown an error message `"No User Profile Application found. Please create a User Profile Application on the farm."`

To Create User Profile Service Applcication i browse to `Central Administration>>Service Applications>>Manage Service Applications`.I tried to create a new User Profile Service Application i had given Name,**Application Pool,Profile DB Name,Social DB Name,Sync DB Name** and clicked **OK**. Then it run for a long time and thrown a `"Request Timed Out Error"`.

So, I am not able to configure MySites With out User Profile Service Application Running on my server. Please help me in finding out a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure that Farm Administrator account must be a Local
  Administrator on the server where the User Profile Synchronization
  Service will be provisioned.
- Navigate to Central
  Administration >> Application Management >> Manage Service Manage
  Application>> Click on New >> Select

[image]

- Enter Name, Application Pool Name and account

[image]

- Now enter the name of other databases like Social, profile etc. I will leave it by default

[image]

[image]

- Now start the User profile service by going into Central Admin >>
  System Service>> Manage Services on the server
  [image]
- Now start User Profile Synchronization Service by giving the Farm admin credentials

[image]

- Make sure that ForeFront Identity Manager Services (FIM) are correctly configured and started
  [image]
- Perform an IISReset and go get a coffee cup :)
- Now, set up the sync connection by going to Manage Service Application > User Profile Service > Configure Synchronization Connection > Create new Connection (Note sync account in this case, dev_spadaccount must be granted the Create Child Objects (permissions) on the OU you are Syncing with.
  [image]
- Populate the containers and select the required AD's Organization
  Unit to be Synced. Click on and Start the Full Import.
- Remove the Farm account from local admins on the box running FIM

Happy SharePointing!

Answer (score 0):

Having had a very similar problem, along with many other associated problems, which put my work at an altogether unacceptable, extended standstill, I decided to post the resolution I found to as many forums relating to this issue that I could.

The resolution that I found was one of two things that I did at the same time. (duh – not a smart tactic, but I was getting desperate…) I am not willing to spend the time to isolate the effects of each of these motions, so it could be one, or the other, or both.

1. I noticed that SharePoint was moving the Farm Account Security Managed Account (The user account that Farm Account uses for credentials) from the Administrators group, to the WSS_ADMIN_WPG group. In my case Central Admin was being run on the same machine as the SharePoint Server. I run a single server developer environment. So the Farm Account needed “Log on Locally” privileges. WSS_ADMIN_WPG group did not appear to have the needed privilege, where the Administrators group did. Strangely enough though, the Administrators group is a member of the WSS_ADMIN_WPG group. So I moved the above mentioned user account back into the Administrators group.

Let me know if I’m not seeing something here.

2. Upon examining the SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool (the name I gave for the Security Token Service’s Application Pool), I notice that the Enable 32-bit Applications setting under the Advanced Settings had been set to True. This to me was strange as I remembered installing the 64 bit versions of everything, because the Server machine on which I was working was indeed 64 bit. So I set it to False.

After those two simple motions I did all the familiar and necessary things to be done to make sure that the system and SharePoint was running with all the latest settings and tried what I had been doing once again, and to my amazement and shock (after having tried everything on the internet several times each) it worked! I am now happily moving forward in my work! At least until the next roadblock comes along.

Weird, dumb and stupid, what were the chances? Maybe it will be worth a quick look for you.

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/159686/6382). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure, you have DB connection and permissions to create the Database in DB Server.

I'm very much sure, user profile will be created.

Comment: This question is pretty old and well answered. I think your answer is not needed at this point. By the way - your answer is not very helpful.